# Can any PixelFormat be used with any ImageFormat?

Tags: .net, system.drawing

**Can any PixelFormat be used with any ImageFormat?**

I'm doing some image processing using System.Drawing.Bitmap. When I create the Bitmap I'm asked for a PixelFormat; when I save the Bitmap, I'm asked for an ImageFormat. Are there any invalid combinations here?

---

To assist answering, here is the list of PixelFormats and ImageFormats:

PixelFormats ([MSDN - System.Drawing.PixelFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat.aspx)):

```
Gdi*
Alpha*
PAlpha*
Extended*
Canonical*
Undefined*
DontCare*
Max*
Format1bppIndexed
Format4bppIndexed
Format8bppIndexed
Format16bppGrayScale**
Format16bppRgb555
Format16bppRgb565
Format16bppArgb1555
Format24bppRgb
Format32bppRgb
Format32bppArgb
Format32bppPArgb
Format48bppRgb
Format64bppArgb
Format64bppPArgb
```

* - Causes ArgumentException when passed to new Bitmap()
** - Doesn't work with any ImageFormat

ImageFormats ([MSDN - System.Drawing.ImageFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.aspx)):

```
Bmp
Emf
Exif
Gif
Icon
Jpeg
MemoryBmp
Png
Tiff
Wmf
```

**EDIT 1**:
Updated PixelFormat list with PixelFormats that cause an exception when creating a Bitmap.

**EDIT 2**: 
By doing some of my own testing, it seems that the PixelFormat "**Format16bppGrayScale**" is incompatible with all ImageFormats. Still looking for other incompatibilities...

**EDIT 3**:
It seems to me that using "Format32bppArgb" for ImageFormats that support transparency and "Format24bppRgb" for formats that don't works fairly well.

Comment: How can I clarify my question? Or is this question moot somehow? Please, enlighten me.